# HDMI, Thunderbolt ports not working in Boot Camp

Tags: windows-7, hdmi, macbook-pro, boot-camp, thunderbolt

I've installed Boot Camp on my MacBook Pro, but the HDMI and Thunderbolt ports still aren't working. When I connect an HDMI cable from my Mac to a monitor, the monitor says No HDMI Input.

System:

- Windows 7
- Boot Camp 5.0
- Mac OS X 10.8.4
- MacBook Pro 15" 2013

Is there a more recent version of Boot Camp available? Are specific drivers available somewhere online?

Comment: The version of Bootcamp you would have is based on the version of OS X you have. I would provide that specific information otherwise we have to just guess.  Boot Camp 5.0.5033 is the current version.  If you have installed the drivers http://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1638/en_US/BootCamp5.0.5033.zip then you have everything required for Windows to work.  Do these ports work in OS X?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, the ports work in Mac OS X.

Comment: (original poster) yes they worked previous to boot camping the same issue was there with the USB's and headphone jack although I already found a solution to them. It also acknowledges my wireless apple mouse so I am not sure why the other ports would be unresponsive.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [this link](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Apple-Details-Thunderbolt-Behavior-in-Windows-7-Boot-Camp-208861.shtml) may fit your needs.

It says:

> “While it starts up, Windows 7 scans and activates devices connected directly to the Thunderbolt port. If a device is not directly connected when the computer starts up, Windows 7 will not recognize the device.”
>
> The best way to add and remove devices from the Thunderbolt chain while Windows 7 is running is to plug and / or unplug devices into a Thunderbolt peripheral that is already recognized, Apple reveals.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This should be marked accepted, OP.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone researching  this topic, when trying to solve this we powered everthing down. After that unplug the power for thunderbolt device. Then, plug the power cable back in, restart your mac. The mac will now recognize the display, and install the required drivers.